# How to change my Cloud Identity plan before I put in my billing information

Tags: google-cloud-identity

nice to meet you. I am not good at English so sorry if I am wrong.
I am a new user of Cloud Identity.

I tried to sign up for the Free plan, but when I entered the required information, I was prompted to select a billing plan, which I thought was strange, so I checked.

I checked and found that I had mistakenly tried to register for a Premium plan.

I tried to register again on the registration page for the Free plan, but when I entered the domain name, it said that the domain name was in use and I could not proceed any further.

I would like to know how to cancel the Premium plan without entering my billing information or how to change to the Free plan.

I would like to avoid having to enter my billing information just to change from the Premium plan if possible.

I look forward to your answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting a request to Google Customer to remove the domain, I was able to re-set it.